# ssh config の一部分を別ファイルに書き出したい

Tags: ssh, openssh

前提として、 aws で開発をしていると、 instance の start/stop のたびに IP が変更されたりします。 (EIP を固定すればいい、という説はありますが、それはそれで、 EIP の管理コストがかかります。) このインスタンス(たち)は ssh の方法が少し特殊で、それ用のオプションを指定して ssh しないと、いけない、という問題があります。

そうして思ったのが、一部のインスタンスについては、 aws cli の情報をベースに、さくっと ssh config の形式に変換してそれを読み込んで利用できたらいいな、ということです。

ssh config ファイルを直接ゴリゴリ書き換えるスクリプトは、今設定したいサーバーの設定以外にもスクリプトの影響が波及するので、できればやめたいな、と思いました。

#### 質問

- ~/.ssh/config について、一部情報をファイルに切り出して、そこから読み込むような方法はありますでしょうか。イメージでいうと、 .gitconfig の include のような昨日があればよいなと思っています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSH 7.3以降であれば、そのものずばり`Include`というキーワードで所望の通り分割を行うことができるようです。

> ssh_configの分割にはIncludeキーワードが使えます
>   Includeキーワードは2016-08-01リリースのOpenSSH 7.3から導入されています

参考：
[Includeキーワードでssh_configを分割できるようになった件 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/masa0x80/items/ecb692ad93f7d06a07b0)